# Gist is not parsing Github Flavored Markdown properly (Todo List)

Tags: markdown, gist, github-flavored-markdown

Link to gist example todo list: https://gist.github.com/blenderer/6018a922c6ee7d82416d

File Name: checklist.md
File type: Markdown

**Markdown I'm using:**

```
- [ ] for an empty checkbox
- [x] for a checked checkbox


(same code)
```

As you can see, it works fine in the comment that I posted on the gist. However it doesn't render in the actual md file.

Comment: Looking at the edits on that gist, my guess is the presence or absence of newline at the end of the file. Without a newline, a checked item at the end of the list will not appear checked. With the newline, the checked item appears checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding a new line at the end of the file.